# How to make Firefox debugger abort instead of jumping to the previous frame after clicking 'Resume' when paused on an exception?

Tags: firefox, javascript-debugger

When Firefox debugger pauses on exception and I want to 'continue' (let the exception propagate to the very top of the stack and fail), I press the 'Resume' button (or F8). However instead of propagating until caught, the debugger only jumps one frame up, to the caller.

That means I have to:

- press this button insane amounts of times to get the website responsive again
- or click the cog on the right and disable 'Pause on exceptions', click 'Continue' and re-enable 'Pause on exceptions'.

Both are kind of cumbersome. Is there a way to let the current exception propagate without all the hassle?